# Rigidbody isn't colliding with objects when using rigibody.MovePosition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, rigid-bodies

I am trying to move my Player by touch and make it collides so I wrote this script but the problem is that my player is not colliding with the other objects so how to make it collide so how to fix this?

> ```
> [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;
> private Vector3 targetPosition;
>
> private void Start()
> {
>     targetPosition = transform.position;
>     if (!rb)rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
>     // since this rigibody is going to be moved via code not Physics it should be kinemtic
>     rb.isKinematic = true;
>     // in order to smooth the movement
>     rb.interpolation = RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate;
> }
>
> void Update()
> {
>     if (Input.touchCount > 0)
>     {
>         Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
>
>         if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
>         {
>             targetPosition += Vector3.right * touch.deltaPosition.x * speedmodifier;
>             targetPosition += Vector3.forward * touch.deltaPosition.y * speedmodifier;
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> private void FixedUpdate()
> {
>     rb.MovePosition(targetPosition);
> }
> ```

Comment: Make sure that your collider isn't to thin and try again.

Comment: @MathewHD The collider is like my player

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MovePosition()` with non kinematic rigidbodys, but it will then work like transform.position=newPosition and teleports the object to the new position (rather than performing a smooth transition). Furthermore you can move a kinematic rigidbody object from a script by modifying its Transform Component  but it will not respond to collisions and forces like a non-kinematic rigidbody.

So if you want your rigidbody to be correctly affected by Physics you need to use the `AddForce()` Method and set your rigidBody to `Dynamic`.

**Example:**

```
player.AddForce(new Vector2(speed, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Comment: `Kinematic RigidBodies aren't affected by physics` if this was true then what would be the purpose of having kinematic RigidBodies at all? ;) I understand what you mean but how you phrase it it sounds strange

Comment: they interact yes. What you probably wanted to say and how the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) phrases it is: `You can move a kinematic rigidbody object from a script by modifying its Transform Component
 but it will not respond to collisions and forces like a non-kinematic rigidbody.` Meaning they can **cause** collisions but since they are forcedly moved via code they will not **react** to them (e.g. bouncing back etc)

Comment: You can use `MovePosition()` on non-kinematic rigidbodys... it's perhaps not the intended use case but you absolutely can "[If the rigidbody has isKinematic set to false, it works like transform.position=newPosition and teleports the object to the new position (rather than performing a smooth transition).](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)"